# What is the simplest way to access a subproperty of a navigation property when a view is using the non-navigation object as the model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

What is the canon(simplest) way to access a subproperty of a navigation property when a view is using the non-navigation object as the model?

I have these two models:

```
    public class Transaction
    {
        //  F I E L D S  &  P R O P E R T I E S

        [Key]
        public int TransactionID { get; set; }
        public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
        public decimal TransactionAmount { get; set; }
        public string TransactionCategory { get; set; }
        public string TransactionToOrg { get; set; }
        public string TransactionFromOrg { get; set; }
        public string TransactionDescription { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Account")]
        public int AccountID { get; set; }
        public Account account { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the "parent

```
    {
        //  F I E L D S   &   P R O P E R T I E S
        
        [Key]
        public int AccountID { get; set; }
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
        public string AccountInstitution { get; set; }
        public string AccountType { get; set; }
        public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public decimal AccountBalance { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public User user { get; set; }
    }
```

In the view, I'm trying to access an account name by ''' @T.account.AccountName ''' and it is throwing a null referance. I am in need of a step in the right direction to solve this; it's driving me crazy. Eventually, I will also need to be able to change which Account each Transaction associates with via CRUD. Thanks!

Comment: Views and view modes have no navigation properties. ASP.NET MVC is a web framework, not an ORM or data access library. Navigation properties are used in EF, an ORM. What do you mean by `View`? An ASP.NET View? That doesn't affect the ORM at all. A database view? That would need to be configured in the DbContext's configuration .You haven't posted that though

Comment: You haven't posted any view or action code, or the code that uses the ORM either. It's quite possible the query didn't use `Include` to eagerly load related entities

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos ! Would you be able to make your mention of querying via 'Include()'  an answer so I can mark it as solved? I know this was probably a really rudimentary question but would like to leave it up so others can see the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Select command` on `Account` table by passing `AccountId` as where `parameter` then get the value of `AccountName`
Sample Code

```
var account=db.Accounts.Find(AccountID);
string AccountName=account.AccountName;
```